# Flyway migration via command line not working

Tags: mysql, flyway

I haven't been able to get flyway to run migrations on my project. Directory structure looks like the following:

```
.
├── flyway.conf
└── sql
    └── V1__create_initial_tables.sql
```

Running `flyway migrate` returns:

```
Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db-name> (MySQL 5.7)

WARNING: You are connected to a MySQL database using the MariaDB driver. This is known to cause issues. An upgrade to Oracle's MySQL JDBC driver is highly recommended.

Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.006s)
Current version of schema `<db-name>`: << Empty Schema >>
Schema `<db-name>` is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

Running `flyway info` returns:

```
Schema version: << Empty Schema >>

+----------+---------+-------------+------+--------------+-------+
| Category | Version | Description | Type | Installed On | State |
+----------+---------+-------------+------+--------------+-------+
| No migrations found                                            |
+----------+---------+-------------+------+--------------+-------+
```

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flyway didn't find any migrations. By default, it will look for them in `<install-dir>/sql`.

To override the migrations directory, you need to set `flyway.locations` in your `flyway.conf` file:

```
flyway.locations=filesystem:/path/to/sql
```

or specify it on the command line, e.g.:

```
flyway -locations=filesystem:/path/to/sql migrate
```